# How to detect clicks on toolbar searchview after it's expanded?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

```
mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener {
    // do something
}
```

This is being called when I click on the `scrollView`'s icon but if I write something in the searchbox and there is some text and after that click on the searchbox then this listener won't be called.

**Update**

```
mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener {
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

I want to implement scroll to top behavior when the user clicks on the `SearchView`. It works only the icon is visible but I don't know how to do it if the `SearchView` is expanded.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can solve my problem using Zain idea and an example from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65175943/13091576

I also had to write an onFocusChangeListener, because setOnClickListener only triggers when the AutoCompleteTextView has focus.

```
val autoCompleteTextViewId = mSearchView.context.resources.
getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
val searchAutoCompleteTextView =
    mSearchView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(autoCompleteTextViewId)

searchAutoCompleteTextView?.setOnClickListener {
    memoriesScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
}

searchAutoCompleteTextView?.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if(hasFocus) {
        memoriesScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the first tap on the `SearchView` is a click on the `SearchView` itself; but once the `SearchView` is expanded by a first tap (i.e the search icon is hidden), then next tap events are not detected by the `SearchView` itself, but instead they are detected by its underlying `AutoCompleteTextView`.

You can get access to the underling `AutoCompleteTextView` of the `SearchView` with below snippet, and then use its `setOnClickListener` for doing the same code as you want in  `mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener`

```
val autoCompleteTextViewId = 
         mSearchView.context.resources
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)

val searchAutoCompleteTextView =
    mSearchView.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(autoCompleteTextViewID)

searchAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener {
     // Do the same as you want to do as in `mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener`
     scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

Comment: When I try it in onCreateOptionsMenu then findViewById function returns null.